# Can the order of Byobu tabs be rearranged?

Tags: byobu

Can the order of `Byobu` tabs be rearranged?

I have a group of `Byobu` tabs that are logically related, and I'd like them to be adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only with tmux backend:

<kbd>Ctrl + Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> move window left

<kbd>Ctrl + Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> move window right

You can only move one step at a time but the process is quite intuitive and fast.

Answer (score 5):

While [Byobu](http://byobu.org) doesn't have a hotkey for this, it's possible to move windows using the underlying Tmux functionality.  See the [manpage](http://manpg.es/tmux):

> move-window [-ardk] [-s src-window] [-t dst-window]
>                  (alias: movew)
>            This is similar to link-window, except the window at src-window is moved to dst-window.  With -r, all windows in the
>   session are renumbered in sequential order, respecting the base-index
>   option.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.org).*

Comment: The http://mangp.es/tmux URL seems to point nowhere.

Comment: That was a typo.  Fixed now.  manpg.es/tmux

Comment: Thanks, @Dustin. Just to make it clear to others, an example of a full command (moving window 16 to 5) is: `tmux movew -s 16 -t 5`

Comment: Any idea what the options a, d and k do?

Answer (score 1):

I have <kbd>F12</kbd> set as the escape-sequence, and this works for me for setting the number of the current tab, to set the order of the tabs in Byobu:

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>.</kbd>
3. Type the new number for the tab, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>